# Listbox just shows (Collection) every time I add an item to it

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, listbox

So I have 4 classes (Account.cs/Dashboard.cs/AddAccount.cs/AccountList.cs). The Dashboard.cs is my main form which is contains the listbox and displaying methods. Account.cs sets the account details and contains the ToString method. AddAccount.cs just passes the details to the Account class. Then the AccountList.cs is the class that creates the list.

What I'm struggling to do is display the list items. When I add an item, it puts it in the list but displays it as (Collection). How do I just get it to display the just Account name?

**Account.cs:**

```
public class Account
    {
        //Set the Variable
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string StartingBalance { get; set; }

        public Account()
        {
            AccountName = "Account Name not inserted!";
            AccountNo = "Account Number not inserted!";
            StartingBalance = "Interest not inserted!";
        }

        public Account(string name, string accNo, string staBal)
        {
            AccountName = name;
            AccountNo = accNo;
            StartingBalance = staBal;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Account hit");
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", AccountName, AccountNo, StartingBalance);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class SavingsAcc : Account
    {

        public SavingsAcc()
        {
        }

        public SavingsAcc(string name, string accNo, string staBal) : base(name, accNo, staBal)
        {
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + String.Format("{0,-17}", " (Savings Account)");
        }
    }
```

**Dashboard.cs:**

```
//Gives us access to the AccountList methods
        private AccountList myAccountsList = new AccountList();

        //display the List in the list box
        void DisplayAccounts(List<Account> accounts)
        {
            list_Accounts.Items.Clear();

            //for each account in the list
            foreach (Account account in accounts)
            {
                //add the account object to the list box
                list_Accounts.Items.Add(accounts);
            }
        }

        //Add account button
        private void btn_AddAccountPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddAccount AddAccountForm = new AddAccount();

            //Display form but only process results if OK is pressed
            if (AddAccountForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Account NewAccount = AddAccountForm.GetAccountInformation();  //get new account information
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Account Information:"  + NewAccount);

                //add the account to the list
                myAccountsList.AllAccounts.Add(NewAccount);

                //Display the accounts
                DisplayAccounts(myAccountsList.AllAccounts);
            }
        }
```

**AddAccount.cs:**

```
public Account GetAccountInformation()
        {
            Account a;

            if (radio_SavingsAccount.Checked)
            {
                a = new SavingsAcc(input_AccountName.Text, input_AccountNo.Text, input_StartBalance.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                a = new Account(input_AccountName.Text, input_AccountNo.Text, input_StartBalance.Text);
            }

            return a;
        }
```

**AccountList.cs:**

```
class AccountList
    {
        private List<Account> allaccounts;
        public List<Account> AllAccounts
        {
            get { return allaccounts; }
        }

        public AccountList()
        {
            allaccounts = new List<Account>();
        }

        public void AddCurrent(Account a)
        {
            allaccounts.Add(a);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Dashboard` class, correct line where you're putting instance of class into `ListBox` with `Account`'s property `AccountName`, like this:

```
//for each account in the list
foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    //add the account object to the list box
    list_Accounts.Items.Add(account.AccountName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nino :)

Comment: This isn't using your `ToString()` implementation then; it'll only display the AccountName.

Comment: @Idle_Mind OP said: "How do I just get it to display the just Account name?", not `Account.ToString()`

Answer (score 2):

You've got a simple **typo** in your `list_Accounts.Items.Add()` line.  Remove the `s` in `accounts`, to make it `account`.

Change:

```
//for each account in the list
foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    //add the account object to the list box
    list_Accounts.Items.Add(accounts); // You're adding the entire List<> each time!
}
```

To:

```
//for each account in the list
foreach (Account account in accounts)
{
    //add the account object to the list box
    list_Accounts.Items.Add(account); // Add just each individual account
}
```

Comment: Thank you Idle_Mind